# Wildcard in Sql table name dynamic creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using query string to dynamically loop through table name. Now I need to add a wildcard to the table name so that it picks up new table I get. Example below

```
WHILE @Year_Id <= 2018
    BEGIN
      SET @YearVar = CONVERT(varchar(4), @Year_Id)
      SET @TABLENAME = '[SWDI].[dbo].[hail-'+@YearVar+']'
      SET @SQLQUERY = 'SELECT CELL_ID, LAT, LON, SEVPROB, PROB, MAXSIZE, 
      _ZTIME'+
     ' from '+@TABLENAME+
```

So my earlier tables were hail-2001, hail-2002, hail-2003 till 2017. Now I get tables with name hail-201801, hail-201802..

I want to incorporate the extra 01, 02 as wild card while calling the table.
Thanks a lot for the help. I am new to this.

Comment: Where does 01 and 02 come from? Are these all 12 months, or something else?

Comment: Yes these are months. 201801 for January 2018 and so on.

Comment: You can either query sys.tables with a "hail-" like filter and use a cursor to loop them or use another `WHILE` for your months inside your `WHILE` for your years.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Ezequiel López Petrucci. Your approach worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Uh, no you don't.  You clearly don't have a complete understanding of how tables work in a database or in SQL Server.

You gain *nothing* by having multiple tables with exact same columns and types and whose names are differentiated by numbers or dates.  That is not how SQL works.  You lose a lot:  foreign key references, query simplicity, maintainability, and more.

Instead, include the date column in the data and store everything in one table.

If you are concerned about performance, then you can create an index on the date column to get the data that you need.  Another method (if the data is large) is to store the data in separate data partitions.  [These are an important part of SLQ Server functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes).

Comment: I do agree in general, but partitioning is not available in all editions of SQL Server, and in this case partitioned views can be used to have something similar, in which case, you'll end up with something very similar. It is another question if this is the case here, or just poor database design, but in some cases it is a solution to have this kind of partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not creating these tables. These are already present and coming from the server, basically historical data. I am looping through all of them to create one single table.

Comment: @Pred You can partition in any edition of SQL Server, starting with 2016 SP1. But that's not for performance anyway, that's primarily for data management. Proper indexing is a much better approach for both performance *and* maintainability than a bunch of identical tables with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2016, which is not installed everywhere unfortunately. I totally agree with the facts you and Gordon said, I am just pointing out that sometimes it is an option to have this kind of structure. With a view and with proper constraint on the tables dynamic SQL can be avoided too, however the maintenance cost is higher for sure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . But partitioning has been supported in the enterprise version for a much longer time.

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, you could do something like this:

```
SET @TableName = '[SWDI].[dbo].[hail-'+@YearVar+']';

-- Check if the year table exists
IF (OBJECT_ID(@TableName, 'U') IS NULL) BEGIN
  -- Implement your 'wildcard' logic here
  SET @NumVar = '01';
  SET @TableName = '[SWDI].[dbo].[hail-'+ @YearVar + @NumVar']';
END
```

Another solution would be to have the missing numbered tables as views on top of the existing tables, but this might have negative performance effects.

A third one is to have yearly views on top of the new numbered tables, with clever constraints on the tables and in the view definition, this can have insignificant overhead.

Last, but not least, you should consider to build a partitioned view on top of these tables and maintain that view. You can query the view directly without messing with table names all the time.

**Please read Gordon's answer!**

In any case, I'd hightly suggest to be careful with the dynamic queries. You might want to take a look at functions like `PARSENAME` and `QUOTENAME`.